# Is using mysql ENUM a bad architectural solution?

Tags: mysql, architecture

For me it is like using hardcoded values instead of constant variables in application code. But there are different opinions out there. So I can't really decide for sure.

P.S. For the scope of this question let us assume that performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 16):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve, really.  If performance, as you say, is not an issue, then it's largely down to your philosophy, and the inherent changeability of the data.  If you're using an ENUM to store values for days of the week, to aid human readability, and 'queryability' of the data, then it's a perfectly valid use (and far superior, in some cases, to using numbers, or other representations).  If, however, you're using it to store things like the category a product is in (for which the set of available categories could easily change), then it's a very poor solution.

Comment: The practical drawback is extendability. You can't add a value to the list without updating the entire table. You can't mark values to be historic. The list of values is limited. Although you can have the best of both when you move the list feature to the MVC model of your application and let the column type be CHAR. Unless performance and storage are both key to your application, I would not recommend using enums when the database is used only by applications.

Comment: @James B when you say that "to store things like the category of a product is in, then it's a very poor solution". What solution would you prefer in cases like that?

Answer (score 6):

ENUM is great for data that you know will fall within a static set.

If you are using Mysql 5+, storage [***is almost always better***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html#id719550) with an ENUM type for data in a static set, as the official MySQL reference shows. Not to mention that the data is readable, and you have an extra layer of validation.

If you want to know if using ENUM will be an optimization I recommend using [PROCEDURE ANALYZE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/procedure-analyse.html). This will recommend the proper data type for your columns.

Answer (score 2):

This depends very much on the actual situation, but the point of column types in the first place is to define precisely which values are allowed and which are not. If, in your problem domain, the attribute that you are considering to store as an ENUM value, is *fixed* in the sense that it can't possible have other values, then ENUM is a great choice. An example of that would be gender: `ENUM('male', 'female')` is great, because the chance of a third gender to be added would be very low indeed.

If you are storing values that are more likely to change, then you might consider normalising your data model to a many-to-one relationship instead.

Comment: Suppose you then have to translate this to another language, or suppose business dictates you accept 'M' and 'F' instead.

Comment: @MattK those are application/interface concerns, not data concerns.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but ENUM is mixing interface with data already.  If we wanted this pure data, just use 0 and 1, then.  If you want your DB to have something more readable (such as 'male' and 'female') what if there is a future need to change the data (such as internationalization)?

Comment: There is nothing about 0 or 1 that is inherently male or female. You can't understand the data without the application. That's a downside of using magic numbers instead of ENUMs (exactly how it is in code).

Comment: Sure, but it's just a matter of where you define your application.  In the schema of the database, the data in the database, or in a separate application layer.  MySQL allows you to store this info in the schema layer, which in many ways is the most cumbersome and inflexible place to do so.  There is a reason that ENUM is not an ANSI SQL feature, nor is it supported in most other database systems.

Comment: Amazing how gender identification has changed in a mere 4 years.

Comment: @P.Salmon in fact, this answer proves _exactly_ why using an enum might be a bad choice sometimes. Things you expect to definitely stay the same suddenly change - such is the course of life :)

Answer (score 2):

Not in any way! They have several advantages over a numeric field:

- They are much more readable: UPDATE Person SET state=2 -- What does 2 stand for?
- They have a limited range: If you have only 10 states for a person, why allow the numeric values 11+?
- They can be used just like their numeric counter part: UPDATE person SET state=state + 1

In fact, using numeric values instead of enums is like putting constants into the source code.